# Is there a way I could mirror vertex weight data to the opposite side of the mesh? e.g. from left arm to the right arm?

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

I have all the naming right (forearm.L / forearm.R etc.), now how can I mirror the weight painting to the opposite side so it applies to the opposite bone? I've only seen manual solitions (mirror copying vertex data and pasting it to the other bone and such). Is there a way I could do this automatically? I don't think this would be too hard to implement into blender, so I dont see a reason why this wouldn't be a thing already

Comment: do you mean something faster than copying the vertex group in the Vertex Groups list, then mirror it, then change its suffix with "_R" to make it controlled by the opposite bone?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are talking about this method but I don't know if there's another one. Let say you want to mirror the left arm group to the right.

- If the right group already exists (because you've parented *With Automatic Weight*), delete it.

[image]

- Select the left group and copy it.

[image]

- Now mirror that copy.

[image]

- Give it the correct name, i.e. with the correct suffix. This way the bone that is supposed to control it will automatically do.

[image]

Comment: didn't know about the last part where the bone will automatically assign itself to the correct vertex group. at least that makes it a bit easier, thanks! altough i think they should add it as a feature to do that automatically in the future releases

Answer (score 0):

In the *Tool Tab* of *Sidebar* (hit <kbd>N</kbd> to show/hide) there is an *Options* panel, select *X Mirror* to draw both sides at the same time.

[image: Weight Paint Tool Options]